# How does AngularJS ng-repeat track items by default?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I understand that you can use `track by expr` to specify how items are keyed in a `ng-repeat` directive.

But without `track by`, how does AngularJS identify items?

Could I control how objects are tracked by altering the object, without using `track by`, for example?

From the docs:

> If no tracking function is specified the ng-repeat associates elements by identity in the collection.

But this is not clear. What does "identity in the collection" mean?

Comment: afaik the default is:   it injects an expando property - $$hashKey - into your JavaScript objects take a look at http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-using-track-by-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs-1-2.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you omit the `track by` expression, then angular by default will track by `$$hashkey` which is automatically inserted by angular to your list of objects. `$$hashkey` is refer to as **identity of collection**.

You can find more here [What is the $$hashKey added to my JSON.stringify result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826320/what-is-the-hashkey-added-to-my-json-stringify-result)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I also see that [$$hashkey can even be a function](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/f2b7fffdc0b0ad80cebb24f5fea743e9e4a439d5/src/apis.js#L21).

Comment: @tenfour  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26381247/angularjs-is-hashkey-a-reliable-key/26382609

Answer (score 2):

If the repeat is performed on object keys then the tracking identifier is the key

```
e.g. ng-repeat="(key,value) in thingies"
```

For an array the tracking identifier is determined by calling the hashKey function for each array item. The comments from the hashKey function indicates how this is determined:

- string is string
- number is number as string
- object is either result of calling $$hashKey function on the object or uniquely generated id,
- that is also assigned to the $$hashKey property of the object.

Comment: so maybe track by is not as useful for hashes?

Answer (score 1):

Without a track expression a hash based on the value is computed.
WIth a track expression you can supply your own function to compute the hash if you want that level of control.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>User Defined Indexer</h1>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in data track by getTracker()">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>

    <script>
      var app=angular.module("app",[]);
      app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
        $scope.data=[1,2,3,4,5]
        $scope.getTracker = function(v){
          return Math.random();
        }
      });
      angular.bootstrap(document,["app"]);
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to supply my own hash directly from the object, without having to use `track by`? I basically want my HTML templates to not need to know how to identify an object every time it appears in a `ng-repeat`