# What is angular's algorithm for $$hashKey

Tags: angularjs

I know that angular calculates a $$hashKey for each item in an array if used inside ngRepeat. I've googled but I can't find much about how angular calculates this value. I'm very much interested in how its done because in my application I have repaint issues because these $$hashKey values at some point change but I don't see data changing. So I must be missing something. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you look at the source code :)

Comment: In another thread, people say that it is just a counter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26381247/angularjs-is-hashkey-a-reliable-key?rq=1

Comment: It seem to be a counter, but still angular needs a way to determine if something in an object has changed.